# How do I turn off the accessibility screenreader programmatically/automatically in swift?

Tags: ios, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I need to turn off the accessibility screenreader programmatically/automatically in certain view or viewcontroller

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Iam making app for blind people and I need to turn off the voiceover in one viewcontroller then the voiceover will continue working in the rest of the viewcontrollers

Answer (score 1):

You can't, by design. This is a user preference and you should work with it, not against it.